# How can i close netty log for selenium Java project?

Tags: java, selenium

I updated selenium 4.5.0 but when run my test netty give it an error so added netty-handler dependency to my project. But when run my test I'm seeing too much netty log. How can I close?

[netty logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg8dE.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create logback.xml configuration file under src/main/resources as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```